# C# SqlClient asynch locking up program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqlclient

I've been having difficulty getting my queries in C# to run asynchronously. I followed the example for [`BeginExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) on MSDN, but while the query is running, the program's window is frozen. I want to give some idea that the program is working and not frozen, which I thought is what the Begin/End methods let you do. I swapped out my huge query for a simpler one just for readability here.

```
private void mysqlHandler()
{
    statusLabel.Text = "Connecting to database...";
    string conStr = String.Format("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    //go ahead and set these up
    string commandString = @"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
    //try block for connecting to the database
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        statusLabel.Text = "Querying database";
        //try block for querying the database
        try
        {                    
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteReader();
            //let the user know stuff is happening
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                seconds++;
                int s = seconds % 60;
                int m = (int)Math.Floor((double)seconds / 60);
                queryTimerLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", m, s);
                switch (seconds % 3)
                {
                    case 0:
                        statusLabel.Text = "Querying database.";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        statusLabel.Text = "Querying database..";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        statusLabel.Text = "Querying database...";
                        break;
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //so while loop doesn't take up all the memory or something
            }
            SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(result); //get result
            seconds = 0; //reset time query has taken
            statusLabel.Text = "Query successful";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            showError(err);
            statusLabel.Text = "Error querying database";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        showError(err);
        statusLabel.Text = "Error connecting to database";
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
            con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a while loop AND making your thread sleep for 1 second until it (the query) completes. You aren't doing anything asynchronously here.

You should probably look into [ExecuteReaderAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead if you can, because this loop you're doing is not going to make anything asynchronous.